# Was Jesus lifted up in sprit or whole as a person

Tags: source-identification, prophet-isa, belief

Today watching "Jesus of Nazareth" we were discussing about how Jesus was saved by Allah. There is a contradiction about how Allah saved Jesus. Some believe his spirit was lifted into heaven while the person who was crucified was a look a like, which died taken to burial after which 2-3 days later the coffin was found empty which marks the resurrection.
Some People believes that he was lifted up as a whole person during night and next day the cross was empty.
Can someone tell me what really happened that people are divided on chain of events.